Fill large and deep pothole in concrete driveway without cutting out concrete?


I have a pretty large pothole in my concrete driveway that is slowly getting worse and wreaking absolute havoc on my vehicles. The size is roughly 11.5 ft by 8ft or so, with the deepest section being almost 4 inches.
If I clean the hole out really well, could I use a concrete patcher in layers to fill the hole? Not really worried about cosmetics here just want something that's save to drive over and would hopefully last a few years. Product recommendations and advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Does it smell as well? reek v. wreak... I would suggest doing a rectangular section properly to include the crack extending to the bottom left.

Is it continuing to get worse as time goes on?  For a good repair, you will need to figure out why it's failed in the first place and make sure it's not still sinking or getting larger.  If you're looking for just a quick fix for a few years, the cheapest would be to clean out the junk that's in there and fill in with compacted gravel and re-profile the gravel every few months.  Or possibly some bags of concrete mix that could be done by hand.  To do a professional fix would be to cut out the damaged section(s) down to the sub base and build it up with new concrete.

Note that specific product recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic.  It's fine to request general techniques, but not for specific products.

You could try some kind of feather-edge repair, but I wouldn't be sanguine about its durability.  But if you can rent a concrete saw to square off the edges at least 2" deep, you could use a regular concrete mix to fill the hole.

Since you don't want to cut/remove concrete, which would be the right way to do it, get a bag of high strength concrete mix and fill in the large hole and work it out to the edges. Don't use the patch stuff to fill in the large hole because you have to layer that stuff a 1/4" at a time and wait for it to dry. Concrete mixes don't do well on feathered edges so when those chip off, you can then use the concrete patch as needed.
